# Flat morphism of local rings

Tags: algebraic-geometry, flatness, local-rings, cohen-macaulay, regular-rings

Let $(A,m_A)$ and $(B,m_m)$ be two Noetherian local rings, $A \subseteq B$
and $B$ is a finitely generated $A$-algebra.

**Step 1:** Assume that:

**(1)** $A$ is [regular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_local_ring#:%7E:text=In%20commutative%20algebra%2C%20a%20regular%20ring%20is%20a%20commutative%20Noetherian,equal%20to%20its%20Krull%20dimension.).

**(2)** $A \subseteq B$ is flat.

> **Question 1:** Why $B$ is [Cohen-Macaulay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohen%E2%80%93Macaulay_ring)?

**Step 2:** Further assume that $m_AB=m_B$, namely, the extension of $m_A$ in $B$ is $m_B$.

> **Question 2:** Why $A \subseteq B$ is [unramified](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unramified_morphism)?
> For more details on unramifiedness, see [this](http://math.uchicago.edu/%7Eamathew/chetale.pdf).

(Then flat+ unramified= etale, and hence $B$ is actually regular, see [a](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/175766/formally-smooth-map-from-a-regular-ring?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [b](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/207595/when-a-smooth-algebra-is-regular) or [c](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/025P)).

Please see [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/390649/local-rings-r-subsetneq-s-with-r-regular-and-s-cohen-macaulay-non-regula/390651?noredirect=1#comment995737_390651) question.

Thank you very much!

**Edit:** Now I asked the above Question 2 at [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/390831/is-the-following-local-map-unramified).

**Edit 2:** The definition of an unramified (local) ring extension can be found [here](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/024L).

Comment: The second statement is false - consider any non-separable field extension.

Comment: Thank you for the comment! Please, could you explain or give a link to the first statement/ question? Also, maybe I misunderstood the explanation in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/390649/local-rings-r-subsetneq-s-with-r-regular-and-s-cohen-macaulay-non-regula/390651?noredirect=1#comment995737_390651, so could you explain what was meant there (there were additional conditions in that question).

Comment: I don't have anything constructive to say at this time about the first statement. I don't see how the linked explanation gets around the counterexample I posed. Perhaps you should ask the person who wrote it.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the help. I will later ask him about your counterexample. Maybe you are talking about different definitions, I do not know. Actually, I have already asked him in previous comments why $m_AB=m_B$ implies unramifiedness of $A \subseteq B$ and he gave an exact reference in EGA 4, 4, Theorem 17.4.1 (d'') https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~leila.schneps/grothendieckcircle/pubtexts.php

Comment: The referenced statement in EGA tells you that a morphism $f:X\to Y$ with $f(x)=y$ is unramified if and only if $\mathfrak{m}_y\mathcal{O}_{X,x}=\mathfrak{m}_x$ and $k(x)$ is a separable extension of $k(y)$. Your condition is the first half of this statement and makes no reference to the second half, which is exactly where the counterexample I gave comes from.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, which slightly clarifies things for me (however, there are still unclear things). What if we take $A$ and $B$ to be algebras over $\mathbb{C}$ for example? Should this help?

Comment: If I am not wrong, the answer is positive if $A$ and $B$ are $\mathbb{C}$-algebras, according to the first lines in the following answer: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/3639/what-does-ramification-have-to-do-with-separability, so perhaps in the other question he assumed that $A$ and $B$ are $k$-algebras, where $k$ is a perfect field.

Comment: But maybe I am wrong, and $A/m_A \subseteq B/m_B$ is not separable? (this is a question in field theory now; could such a field extension be non-algebraic?).

Comment: Let me slightly correct my last statement - I should have said "a morphism $f:X\to Y$ **locally of finite presentation** with $f(x)=y$ is unramified if and only if $\mathfrak{m}_y\mathcal{O}_{X,x}=\mathfrak{m}_x$ and $k(x)$ is a **finite** separable extension of $k(y)$." I have grown tired of this conversation and will no longer be replying. Good day.

Comment: Ok, sorry, thank you for your helpful comments!